# Sending text file contents through SOAP in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I want to send text file contents that vary from KB to MB through SOAP.
The problem is that for text content more than 16 MB the SOAP client will give error:
`SOAP fault: Invalid XML`.
For SOAP request less than 16 MB it works fine.
I tried option like increasing

1. time out
2. memory size
3. post size

But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the server you're sending it to has been configured to accept large submissions? MS based servers have various knobs and configuration tweaks required to accept large submissions.

My suggestion is for you to set up a small SOAP server (preferable non-MS) that you can test your submissions against first.